# Sniffing wireless LAN network using tcpdump

Tags: wireless-networking, sniffing

If I correctly understood the basics of the wireless working, I should be able to sniff the traffic of other computers over the wireless LAN. 
So I connected a second computer to my wireless LAN and tried to see if I was able to sniff its `http` traffic through the network, using `tcpdump` with a command like this:

```
sudo tcpdump -v -i wlan0 dst 10.0.0.7
```

while `10.0.0.7` is the ip of the computer that I want to sniff over the LAN.
But unfortunately, I get nothing as output (excepted ICMP echo requests if I `ping 10.0.0.7`, so `tcpdump` works fine :) ).

What am I missing?

Comment: what does `dst` mean to tcpdump?

Comment: @schroeder: `dst` mean that I'm listening only the packets for which the `destination` field is `10.0.0.7`

Comment: right - and how would that be the case from your machine?

Comment: @schroeder: I thought I could simply sniff the packet directed from the default gateway to the computer I want to sniff. Because since the packets are transmitted over the wifi, I should be able to `hear` them although I'm not the recipient. `10.0.0.7` is the ip address of the computer I want to sniff, and `10.0.0.8` is my ip address.

Comment: That depends on the type of wifi you are using... It doesn't act like a hub, but a switch.

Comment: @schroeder: I don't understand how the wifi router could act like switch since the data is transmitted "in the air".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to set your network interface into **monitor mode** to be able to sniff all traffic on the wireless network. So, before starting up `tcpdump`, do the following:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode Monitor
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

This will simply turn off your interface, enable monitor mode and turn it on again. Note that not all network interface cards support monitor mode.

To reset your NIC back to normal, issue the same commands, but with `mode Managed` .

On a side note, the traffic on your sniffer will most likely not look how you will expect it to look, due to any encryption schemes your router uses. Considering that you are sniffing your own network, you will be able to decrypt the traffic in most cases though. 
[Here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11) is a short overview on how to do it on `Wireshark`, an alternative to `tcpdump` that also features a graphical user interface. If you prefer to keep `tcpdump` for capturing, you can also use its `-w` option to dump traffic to a `.pcap` file and later open that file in Wireshark (or any other packet analyzer).

Note that if your network uses WPA or WPA2 encryption, you will need to capture the respective handshakes between router and each device you want to monitor. The Wireshark wiki article I linked explains how to do so:

> WPA and WPA2 use keys derived from an EAPOL handshake, which occurs when a machine joins a Wi-Fi network, to encrypt traffic. Unless all four handshake packets are present for the session you're trying to decrypt, Wireshark won't be able to decrypt the traffic. You can use the display filter eapol to locate EAPOL packets in your capture.
>
> In order to capture the handshake for a machine, you will need to
>   force the machine to (re-)join the network while the capture is in
>   progress.

Comment: @zinfandel: Thanks a lot! I understood now. So if I correctly understood the connection between each computer and the access point is encrypted, while using WPA, or WPA2 encryption?

Comment: Yes, traffic is encrypted on a "protected" network, i.e. one using WEP, WPA, or WPA2.

Comment: @zinfandel: Could you explain why i have to choose Monitor mode over Promiscuous mode? Thanks :)

Comment: @SamBruns Monitor mode is WiFi's version of Promiscuous mode.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you didn't specify if this was an open network or WPA protected. That makes a difference. I'll assume it's WPA because you are experiencing problems.

You are not the man in the middle. The packets from 10.0.0.7 are going from that computer directly to the gateway (i.e. 10.0.0.1) and out to the internet, bypassing you. You need to arp spoof and insert yourself between the gateway and that user (10.0.0.7). There are many tools to do that. Typically you first set up ip forwarding in your kernel, then run a command like `arpspoof <victim ip> <gateway ip>`

Comment: First of all: thanks for answering! I see. But I don't manage to understand the need for arp spoofing. Why can't I simply sniff the packet being transmitted over the LAN? Could you explain, or redirect me to some learning material? Thanks!